# Adventure book with a sword that needed to be reforged and some dwarves, possibly published around 25 years ago

Tags: story-identification, books, choose-your-own-adventure

It was an adventure book where the reader could choose various paths for the hero to take (i.e. if you want to do X go to page 20). I remember a sword that needed to be reforged, some dwarves (blatant rip off of LOR). It was perhaps 100 pages and written for children who have not long learned to read I think.

Comment: Sounds like one of the [Choose Your Own Adventure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choose_Your_Own_Adventure) books.  [Something like 400](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Choose_Your_Own_Adventure_books) of them have been published so far (including the spinoffs).

Comment: Can you remember any other details about the book?

Comment: Coming back to this after 10 years :). I can't remember any other details sorry. I think the top answer looks very familiar though. Might have to get my hands on a copy and check it out. A belated thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I wonder if this might be [Runesword](https://gamebooks.org/Item/793/Show), from the [Dragontales](https://gamebooks.org/Series/121/Show) series, published in 1984. (Found via Google Books.) From inside the book:

[image: Google Books screenshot]

> THE SWORD REFORGED! The dwarf king kneels by the fire pit, waiting for you. You hold the hilt forward and the end of the sword that broke from it. You hold it until you can't stand the heat, then thrust the glowing pieces together

That said, Demian's site describes the books in the series as "being about two hundred pages in length", not the 100 you remember.

[image: cover showing a skeleton king and a boy: "Choose a pathway to the magical realms"]

Comment: I've done a rollback on the last edit. I think typing in the text from the book was a good idea, but not deleting the Google Books screenshot. If the user in question (@Laurel) redoes the edit, but this time leaves the screenshot in place, I reckon that should be OK.

Comment: Transcribing the text is essential so that every reader (including those who use screen readers) can understand the answer in its entirety, equally. What is the significance of showing it came from Google Books?

Comment: @Laurel I do agree that we should include the transcription. As for showing it came from Google Books, often when someone posts an answer other people want to know how they found it. This shows that Google Books was used, and highlights my search terms in bold. It helps people confirm my source, since there aren't any actual screenshots of the pages to include in this post.

Comment: This looks very familiar. I'll take a look at it thank you. Took a while to get the answer and for me to reply, but got there in the end :)

Comment: @user13238 Glad I was able to finally find it for you!

Comment: Mods - question asked May 2013, answered March 2022 (nearly nine years later), answer accepted March 2023 (nearly ten years after the question was asked). Have I broken the "longest time between question ask and answer accepted" record for the Story ID tag?

Answer (score 3):

I remember the Lone Wolf CYOA's from forever ago (ie late 80's/early 90's). Not really for kiddies, but there you go. Wouldn't mind cracking one of those open again... no matter how dated and silly it would be. This probably isn't your answer, but it might be. Most of these were series of books. Lone Wolf had... 60+ I think, and there were others, though I don't care to try to remember them.

Comment: I also read (played?) several of the Lone Wolf CYOA books in the 90s. When I looked around a few years ago, several of them were available in HTML form.

Comment: How does this match the question, other than that it's a gamebook series (of which there are dozens).

Comment: Lone Wolf had 20 books in the original series, and four books in the Grey Star spin-off series, plus eight books in the New Order series in the 1990s. According to Wikipedia, one more was published in the 2010s and there were three planned for publication after that, so the total is at most 36, not 60+. I think, @Jersey, you've confused *Lone Wolf* with *Fighting Fantasy*, since FF DID have approximately 60 books in the main series.

Comment: If an answer contains "This probably isn't your answer" then it shouldn't be an answer.